# Meaning of Phase Angle

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ethernet, phase, phy

In this [Application Note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla327/slla327.pdf?ts=1665732057574&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), section 3.1,

Can someone help me to understand the meaning of "magnitude of phase angle of the load" in simple terms?

Phase angle between Rx and Tx or what does phase angle of the load mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right at the start of section 3 it says this: -

> **The specification requirements of the return loss for both magnitude
> and phase for an unshielded twisted pair must be greater than 16 dB at
> 2 MHz, with an impedance range of 100 ±15 Ω, nominally resistive with
> a phase angle less than 3° over the frequency range of 2-to-80 MHz
> (ANSI INCITS 263-1995).**

It's talking about the purity of the characteristic impedance of the twisted pair cable but, in section 3.1 it's implying that the series coupling capacitors and internal termination resistors must not look reactive by more than 3° hence, this dictates that 33 nF (a standard value) capacitors need to be used in series with the 100 Ω termination to ensure this specification is met at 2 MHz.

2 x 33 nF couple the 100 Ω terminator hence, the net capacitance is 16.5 nF and, at 2 MHz this has a reactive impedance of 4.83 Ω. Arctan of 4.83/100 = phase angle = 2.76°.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Phase angle of 3 deg is between which two signals?

Comment: And what does it mean by "phase angle of the load"?

Comment: It's the phase angle of the load itself. A resistor has a phase angle of 0 degrees, a capacitor has a phase angle of 90 degrees. The two capacitors and 100 ohm terminator need to offer a phase angle of less than 3 degrees.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But where are the 2 capacitors? There is only one capacitor on the figure ?\

Comment: Figure 5 has two capacitors on the TX circuit and two capacitors on the RX circuit. In effect they are in series @Newbie

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted the answer. Just a small clarification, why should the phase angle be less than 3deg? Any idea?

Comment: @Newbie design-by-committee by the ANSI INCITS 263-1995 folk. I expect it can be a tad more but then it won't meet the spec.

Comment: Ok thank you :)